how to stop pyspark from recalculating result everytime i run display function
I got a pyspark code that run a spark sql to read a data from a table and then assign a random number to each row. Final output is then stored in a dataframe. But every time I access that dataframe i get different result ( different random number assigned).
How do i make sure that the sql is run only once and dataframe content dont change afterwards?
test_df = spark.sql(
f"""with op as (
select file_name, round((rand()*10)) as rnd from test_table """ )
display(test_df)
Everytime I run display(test_df) i see different random number assigned to a file name. I tried caching result but no luck. I just want that random number once assigned to filename to stay the same.

which dataframe are you caching? how are you caching? please add more details

test_df.cache().
Everytime I run display(test_df) it returns a different result (different random number assigned)
I also found that behaviour is different among cluster type. Not working in general purpose cluster but working as expected in Single user cluster. Bit strange

Random numbers in distributed systems like Spark are tricky. The two general approaches I follow are (1) Don't use them. Often times, a hash of a column is good enough. For example, in your case you might use a hash of the filename instead of a random number. (2) If you truly need a random number, generate it once and persist it.
